# Image hover always display in same position

Tags: html, css, image, hover, html-lists

I am currently working on a image hover color selector. 
There are 3 color selectors floating to the right, with smaller squared-size. And when I hover on them, their enlarged image will be shown by their left side and always display on the same position for any small image I hovered on. 
[image: Hover to display enlarged Image in Grey area]

[image: Hover covering other DIV]

I have come up with some code in this link: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sammmmi/90podmry/).
But the result is not as expected. I guess no javascript is required for this one but I don't know how to place them all in the same position.

```
ul.color_selector li:hover span.color_detail img{
display:inline-block;
float: left;
padding-left:0px;
padding-top:-3px;
top: -105px;
left: -210px;}
```

Would anyone please provide me some help, thank you so much!

Comment: i am not sure but i think it would be easier if you use javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've made you a simple example with only CSS that achieves what you want.
there are some down-sides in using just CSS to do this ( html structure, fixed `padding-left` etc. ) but it does the job :)

you should be able to adapt my code easily

Let me know if this helps you

See **snippet** below or **[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/meemjfgt/)**

```css
ul.colors {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  list-style:none;
  position:relative;
   padding-left:220px;
}
li.color {
  
  display:inline-block;
}
li.color img:first-child {
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  cursor:pointer;
 
}
li.color img:last-child {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  opacity:0;
  transition:0.3s;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}
li.color img:first-child:hover + img {
  opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="colors">
 <li class="color color1">
  <img src="https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/color-burn.png">
  <img src="https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/color-burn.png">
 </li>
 <li class="color color2">
  <img src="https://files.graphiq.com/2307/media/images/t2/Islamic_Green_429772_i0.png">
  <img src="https://files.graphiq.com/2307/media/images/t2/Islamic_Green_429772_i0.png">
 </li>
 <li class="color color3">
  <img src="https://files.graphiq.com/2307/media/images/t2/Deep_Sky_Blue_429606_i0.png">
  <img src="https://files.graphiq.com/2307/media/images/t2/Deep_Sky_Blue_429606_i0.png">
 </li>
 <li class="color color4">
  <img src="https://files.graphiq.com/2307/media/images/Banana_Yellow_429852_i0.png">
  <img src="https://files.graphiq.com/2307/media/images/Banana_Yellow_429852_i0.png">
 </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! I have implemented your code, but the hover image didn't appear. I was think will it be the styling problem. Because from my original coding the color selector is in the middle of my website and it is wrapped by a div. The hover image is supposed to be appearing on top of other div of the page. It may be hard to understand but I have included an new image to explain my idea. Or actually I should not use pure CSS to achieve?

Comment: I can imagine I should use a loop to calculate the spacing between each tiny box and to place them to the same position for each increment of looping... But I am not sure how to do it so I have done it with pure CSS

Comment: with pure css you cannot make relations between the small colors and the larger colors...if they are not related ( same div, siblings, parent > child etc. ) . my code worked because the 2 imgs are in the same div one after the other ( small first, large second ) .  you need to share the HTML structure and a JQ solution would be best. For what you have shared in your Original Question, my solution is the answer.

Comment: ＠Mihan T you have really given me a good example and now I can achieve with the outcome I wanted by setting them into different classes and changing the individual value for each classes. It may be quite a dumb way but i already achieved what I expected... Thank you so much again for your inspiration!!!